# Best way to create many branching arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I could write shorthand objects, but then I'll have a ton of indents of other arrays and objects inside. This is for a question form with many branching new sets of questions based on the last one anawered. Any suggestions on how this code should be designed?

Comment: What matters is how the data is laid out. If all of the questions are unique based on the previous answer then you don't have too much choice beyond what you initially suggested. If some questions lead to the same paths then you'll want a more complex data structure, such as a directed graph. But Stack Overflow isn't really for brainstorming data structures, it's for solving strictly defined problems. Look into directed graphs and graph construction. [Here's a post on dialog trees](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/how-do-dialog-trees-work) which is basically what you're making.

Answer (score 1):

Use tree structure like this:

```
var
n0 = {/*data*/},
n1 = {/*data*/},
...
n3234 = {/*data*/}
n0.children = [n1, n2, n3]
n1.children = [n11, n12, n13]
...
n3234.children = []
```

If you reuse subtrees, just make this:

```
n2321 = n1234,
```

Avoid cycles like this:

```
n2222 = n2,
...
n1111.children = [n1]
```

Comment: One thing I don't understand about your example is that it lists out children that haven't yet been defined.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution with less typing:

```
var d = {
'':  {/*data*/},
'1': {/*data*/},
'1.1': {/*data*/},
..
'3.2.3.4': {/*data*/}
}
for(var k in d){//init child array
  d[k].children = []
}
for(var k in d){//build tree structure
  if(k != ''){//skip root
    var a = k.split('.')//hierarchy array
    var i = a.pop()//remove my level
    var parent = a.join('.')
    if(parent in d){//parent exists
      d[parent].children.push({i: +i, k: k})//to prevent holes
    }
    else {
      console.log('pending subtree: ' + k)
    }
  }
}
for(var k in d){//transform child array
  d[k].children = d[k].children
    .sort(function(a, b){return a.i - b.i})//es6 (a, b)=>a.i-b.i
    .map(function(x){return d[x.k]})//es6 x=>d[x.k]
}
//now the tree is in d['']
```

Comment: There's an error on the hole prevention. (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd[parent].children.push')). What should be put there?

Comment: @VagueExplanation child array initiation added and join corrected. It is not a tested code, you have to finalize it by yourself...